# Multiple submit buttons not working

Tags: php

I am looking for a solution to multiple submit buttons using simple php.

Here is my form code

```
                <!-- Widget Starts -->
                <div class="widget">
                    <div class="title js_opened">
                        <div class="icon"><img src="themes/<?php echo WEBSITE_ADMIN_PANEL_THEME; ?>/images/icons/navigation/pages<?php echo $retina_suffix; ?>.png" width="24" height="24" alt="" /></div>
                        <span>Fill The Fields Marked With *</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="form_row first">
                            <label>Title<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                            <div class="form_right"><input type="text" name="title" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $session->getSession("pages_title") ;?>" /></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row last">
                            <label>Description<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                            <div class="form_right"><textarea name="description" class="Editor"><?php echo $session->getSession("pages_description") ;?></textarea></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Widget Ends -->

                <!-- Widget Starts -->
                <div class="widget">
                    <div class="title js_opened">
                        <div class="icon"><img src="themes/<?php echo WEBSITE_ADMIN_PANEL_THEME; ?>/images/icons/navigation/meta<?php echo $retina_suffix; ?>.png" width="24" height="24" alt="" /></div>
                        <span>Metadata Information</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="form_row first">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <div class="form_right"><input type="text" name="meta_title" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $session->getSession("pages_meta_title") ;?>" /></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label>Keywords</label>
                            <div class="form_right"><textarea id="meta_keywords" name="meta_keywords"><?php echo $session->getSession("pages_meta_keywords") ;?></textarea></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <div class="form_right"><textarea id="meta_description" name="meta_description"><?php echo $session->getSession("pages_meta_description") ;?></textarea></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label>Robot</label>
                            <div class="form_right">
                                <select name="meta_robot">
                                    <option value="">Please Choose An Option</option>
                                    <option value="index, follow" <?php if ($session->getSession("pages_meta_robot")=="index, follow") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?> >index, follow</option>
                                    <option value="noindex, follow" <?php if ($session->getSession("pages_meta_robot")=="noindex, follow") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?> >noindex, follow</option>
                                    <option value="index, nofollow" <?php if ($session->getSession("pages_meta_robot")=="index, nofollow") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?> >index, nofollow</option>
                                    <option value="noindex, nofollow" <?php if ($session->getSession("pages_meta_robot")=="noindex, nofollow") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?> >noindex, nofollow</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row last">
                            <label>Author</label>
                            <div class="form_right"><input type="text" name="meta_author" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $session->getSession("pages_meta_author") ;?>" /></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Widget Ends -->

                <div class="form_buttons">
                    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Save" />&nbsp;<span class="no_mobile">&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Save &amp; New" />&nbsp;<span class="no_mobile">&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                </div>
                </form>
                <!-- Form Ends -->
```

and here is my php processing page code (I have omitted the part which saves the form results into the database.

```
<?php
$submit = $_POST["add"];
if ($submit == "Save")
{
header("location:pages_view.php?type=success&msg=" .urlencode($msg));
exit();
}
else
{
header("location:pages_add.php?type=success&msg=" .urlencode($msg));
exit();
}
?>
```

What I want to achieve is that if I press the 1st submit button in form i.e Save, then it should save the form and go to view page and if I press the 2nd submit button i.e Save & New then it should save the form data and go back to the same page i.e add page.

Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag in your actual code?

Comment: Yes i have the <form> tag there. Just copied part of the code here to use as reference.

Comment: Right now its using else condition no matter i click on save button or save and new button, its always to redirecting to view page

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the name of the submit button is set, and do the operation based on it.

For example:

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') // if form is submitted...
  {
    if(isset($_POST['save'])) // check whether it is the "Save" button that's being clicked
    {
      //code for saving
      echo 'saved';
    }
    else  // it's the "Save & New" button
    {
      //code for save and new
      echo 'save and new';
    }
  }
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="msg" />
    <!-- and other input elements goes here.. -->

    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" name="savenew" value="Save & New" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is not working my friend. I have tried it. Else part is executed everytime the form is submitted no matter i use either of submit buttons

Comment: And yes the name of the submit button is set already. Here is the code for the same.
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Save" />&nbsp;<span class="no_mobile">&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Save &amp; New" />&nbsp;<span class="no_mobile">&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />

Comment: Did you noticed that I have used different names for the two buttons! When you submit a form, the "name" and "value" pair would be available at the server side (in `$_GET` or `$_PSOT` associative arrays, depending upon the method(GET/POST) used ). So, in my code, if you submit the form, at server side the `$_POST` array would contain two elements. One is for the `msg` with it's value and the other would be the name of the button that clicked with it's value. So, I am using the `name` to check which button the user had clicked.

Comment: I have tested the code before posting it. So, I don't think it's the problem with the code. Instead, problem with how you had implemented it in your current scenario. If you want to test my code, just create a php file with the above code and run it.

Comment: I have just checked it, ur code is working but in my case, the submit button key and value pair is not included in the post array. I echo the post array using print_r ($_POST); but the submit button key value pair is not included in it. Dont know why. As a result of that the value remains empty and else condition is fired every time. Posting my full code below. Please check and try to figure it out whats wrong.

Comment: Here is the frontend page code. www.checkwebsitedemo.com/pages_add.txt and here is the form action page code www.checkwebsitedemo.com/pages_add_process.txt

Comment: Did you coded the whole thing? It looks like there is a class called `Form` which parses the submitted data. So, the name & value pairs could be accessed through the object of that class. That class has a `getFormData()` method, and you are calling it and you are storing the array returned. ie, in `$formData`. Thus you might be able to access the button names via `$formData["save"]` or `$formData["savenew"]`. I think that `Form` class is implicitly unsetting the `$_POST` array, after you read the data using the `getFormData()` method.

Comment: Yes i coded the whole thing. No the getFormData() method doesnt effects the post array. Check out the class details www.checkwebsitedemo.com/class.form.txt  I print_r ($formData) as well but it also doesnt includes the key value pair for save or savenew. Dont know why. Please check it and let me know if you figure anything.

Comment: I changed the form method to get from post and these are the form variables appended to the url http://localhost/mywebsite/pages_add_process.php?title=Test&description=%3Cp%3ETest%3C%2Fp%3E&meta_title=&meta_keywords=&meta_description=&meta_robot=&meta_author=  If you can notice that there is no save or savenew variable in the url.

Answer (score -1):

Make a hidden field somewhere in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" value="" name="add">
```

Make two buttons:

```
<button onclick="formSubmit(save)">Save!</button>
<button onclick="formSubmit(something)">Something else!</button>
```

Then apply some Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function formSubmit(tobesend) {
document.getElementById("myHiddenField").value(tobesend);
document.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

What this does is: when a button is clicked, the value to the hiddenfield is set to something, and then the form is submitted. In your PHP-file you can check for the value of $_POST['add'] and do whatever you want to be done.

NOTE: i'm fairly new to javascript, so this might be a nonfunctional code. It's merely to show how to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: There's no need to rely on javascript for critical functionality like this. If multiple submit inputs have name/value pairs, only the clicked button will have its value sent (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)